# Print Preview in Ubuntu system print dialog

Tags: gnome, printing, system-settings

Is there no print preview feature in the system dialog? I was hoping to see something here:

[image]

Alternatively, is there an apt package or alternative gnome printer dialog I can use to achieve this?

Comment: if you click on `Print`, does it not offer you "Print to File"?

Comment: The “print to file” option exists in the general tab depicted above. I would like to preview the job before actually printing though